# "where" in relation of eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

`owner` it's a column of `bulletins` table which is relation in Conversations model.

```
public function bulletin()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Bulletins','bulletin_id');
}
```

---

```
    $conversations = Conversations::with('bulletin','messages')
        ->where('owner_id', $userId)
        ->orWhere('owner', $userId)
        ->get();
```

I got unknown column owner. I know what it mean, but how to do this in laravel? Before I used left join for this request and now I want to use eloquent relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you have it twice? So is the column name `owner` or `owner_id`?

You should be able to do it like this:

```
$conversations = Conversations::with(['bulletin' => function($query) use ($userId) {
    $query->where('owner_id', $userId);
}, 'messages'])->get();
```

Comment: I need both column in 'where' owner and owner id. Original query was:   ->where('owner_id', $userId)
   ->orWhere('owner', $userId)

Comment: Then you need to use the table as alias in front of the column, for example `bulletin.owner_id` and the `owner` column is part of which table?

Comment: `$conversations = Conversations::with(['bulletin'=>function($q){
     $q->where('own.owner',2);
    },'messages'])
   ->orWhere('owner_id', $userId)
   ->get();`

Comment: it works now, but when using last ->where or ->orWhere - i got empty result

Comment: sorry my mistake - was wrong ID ) thanks - it's solved

Comment: np, happy coding